# What is the max time for a transaction to arrive?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm new to all this, I sent 0.95 ETH from my stock exchange account to Ether wallet and it's over 4 hours gone and still not arrived. can anybody explain ?

Comment: It should only take a couple of minutes. Is your client fully synced yet? Please post a transaction hash here so we can help you. The sending or receiving address would be fine as well

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a client like Ethereum Wallet (Mist) or Parity, you may be waiting for it to synchronised the block chain first. The transaction won't show until the client is synch'ed past the block at which te transaction took place.

I'm not sure what the current synchronisation time is for Mist when it's run for the first time. Perhaps a day or more depending on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are normally confirmed in 15~ seconds.

My first suggestion would be to search for your wallet's address on etherscan.io (or another Blockchain explorer) and see if you can find it there.